# Why do I have to call the constructor of the superclass when defining that of the subclass?

Tags: matlab

I have been struggling with the following problem. Let's say we have a superclass *super*, which is itself handle class, and a subclass *sub* of *super*. The following program **doesn't work**:

**super.m**

```
classdef super < handle
    properties
        x
    end

    methods
        function this = super(value)
            this.x = value;
        end
    end
end
```

**sub.m**

```
classdef sub < super
    methods
        function this = sub(value)
             this.x = 2*value;
        end
    end
end
```

If I run `sub(1)`, it prompts that

```
Not enough input arguments.

Error in super (line 8)
            this.x = value;

Error in sub
```

However, if I simply change `this.x = 2*value` to `this = this@super(2*value)` in **sub.m**, it works perfectly fine now...

From time to time I will have to initialize some properties in the subclass inherited from a superclass in a different way, and that's why I am confused. Must I call the constructor of the superclass in this case?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is explicit in [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/creating-subclasses--syntax-and-techniques.html):

> If you do not explicitly call the superclass constructors from the
>   subclass constructor, MATLAB® implicitly calls these constructors with
>   no arguments. In this case, the superclass constructors must support
>   no argument syntax.

The functional `super.m`:

```
classdef super < handle
    properties
        x
    end

    methods
        function this = super(value)
            if nargin ~= 0
                this.x = value;
            end
        end
    end
end
```